# Очередь queue на С,

Tags: c, очередь

Есть очередь заполненная целыми числами.Нужно создать две новые очереди.В одну поместить отрицательные числа,в другую положительные.Написал кусок,где помещаю отрицательные числа.Не знаю.как засунуть положительные числа в другую очередь и распечатать,выдает ошибку

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct {
    int data[100];
    int head, tail;
} queue;

queue createQueue ();
void enqueue (queue *, int);
int dequeue (queue *);
void printQueue (queue *);

int main () {
    queue L, T,M;
    int val, length;
    system("chcp 1251");
    L = createQueue();
    T.head = 0;
    T.tail = 0;
    length = 0;
    while (L.head != L.tail) {
        val = dequeue(&L);
        length++;
        if (val<0) {

        enqueue(&T, val);
    }
        else
        enqueue(&M, val);   
    //  
    }
    printQueue(&T);
//  printQueue(&M);



    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

queue createQueue () {
    queue Q;
    int n, i, val, flag;
    time_t t;
    Q.head = 0;
    Q.tail = 0;
    printf("Razmer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("random?\n");
    do{
        printf("1-Yes,0-No \n");
        scanf("%d",&flag);
    }while((flag != 1) && (flag != 0));
    t = time(NULL);
    srand(t);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(flag==0) {

            val = rand()%20-10;
            enqueue(&Q, val);
        }
        else{
            printf("Elements: ");
            scanf("%d", &val);
            enqueue(&Q, val);
        }

    return Q;
}

void enqueue (queue *Q, int val) {
    Q -> data[Q -> tail] = val;
    Q -> tail = ++(Q -> tail) % 100;
}

int dequeue (queue *Q) {
    int val;
    val = Q -> data[Q -> head];
    Q -> head = (Q -> head + 1) % 100;
    return val;
}

void printQueue (queue *Q) {
    int i = 0, tmp,l;
    while (Q -> head != Q -> tail) {
        if (i % 50 == 0)
        printf("Queue -: ");
        tmp = dequeue(Q);
        printf("%5d", tmp);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл неинициализированную очередь **M**, описка во влаге случайности, неопределённое поведение в добавлении данных.

```
 T.head = 0;
 T.tail = 0;

      M.head = 0; // !
      M.tail = 0; // !

 length = 0;

     ...

     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(flag/*==*/ != 0) {

            val = rand()%20-10;

     ...
void enqueue (queue *Q, int val) {
    Q -> data[Q -> tail] = val;

    ++(Q -> tail);
    (Q -> tail) %= 100;
    //Q -> tail = ++(Q -> tail) % 100; warning: operation on ‘Q->tail’ may be undefined
}
```